# neo4j EXTRACT with multiple items

Tags: neo4j

I am running a demo example and this query seems to give error.

> MATCH p = (node0:Movie) WHERE node0.title  = "Apollo 13"  RETURN EXTRACT(n in nodes(p) | (ID(n),LABEL(n) ))

is there anything changed in community version **2.1.4** from **2.0.0** for Extract syntax?

The error is:

> Invalid input ',': expected whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR or ')' (line 1, column 96)
>   "MATCH p = (node0:Movie) WHERE node0.title  = "Apollo 13"  RETURN EXTRACT(n in nodes(p) | (ID(n),LABEL(n) ))"
>                                                                                                   ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you want to create tuples you can use collection or map literals:

Btw. you have no path, just a single node.
And you misspelt the `LABELS` function.

```
MATCH p = (node0:Movie) 
WHERE node0.title = "Apollo 13" 
RETURN EXTRACT(n in nodes(p) | [ID(n),LABELS(n)])

MATCH p = (node0:Movie) 
WHERE node0.title = "Apollo 13" 
RETURN EXTRACT(n in nodes(p) | {id:ID(n),labels:LABELS(n)})
```

Answer (score 1):

please change your RETURN Statement to

```
return EXTRACT(n in nodes(p) | (ID(n) + " " + LABELS(n)) ) as extracted
```

Update: See above answer of @MichaelHunger, he put two other ways to get it work with comma separation.